# Laravel 4: Why can I access a model accessor when using first() but not take()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return a number of recent posts from my database, ordered by date, and I then want to select and return the month the post was made in via my model's `getMonthAttribute()` accessor method. To accomplish this, I'm using scoped queries. This all works fine when I use `first()` to return just a single result, but when I use `take(1)` or `take()` with any valid numerical input, I receive the following error:

```
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$month
```

In my model, I have this month attribute accessor:

```
public function getMonthAttribute() {
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$this->date)->format('F');
}
```

and my scoped query to return a variable number of recent posts (the portion of my code that is not working):

```
public function scopeRecent($query, $take = 1) {
    // Replace take with first and I no longer receive the above error.
    return $query->where('status', '=', '1')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->take($take);
}
```

Here is how I'm accessing my data in the view:

```
{{ $post->recent()->month }}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `->first()` returns an eloquent model. Using the `get()` method returns an eloquent collection (an array of eloquent models) instead.  So you must run a foreach over the collection like so:

`@foreach($post->recent() as $recent)
    {{$recent->month }}
@endforeach`

Comment: I think I understand, although you may have missed a word in your sentence: "returns an eloquent model using the get() method returns an eloquent collection".

So even if I `take()` just one entry, it still returns a collection?

Comment: yes  take(1) still returns an array with one model in it.